# Is there a work-around for parameter pack expansion in using declarations

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, using-declaration

[Parameter pack expansion in using declarations is not supported in C++14](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-discussion/lscp3Bn2TkA), and so the following code fails to compile:

```
template<typename T>    struct A 
{
    virtual void foo(T);
};

template<typename... T>    struct B: public A<T>...
{
    using A<T>...;
};
```

Is there a work-around to achieve the same results? Otherwise, one would have to manually spell out the using declaration for expected types, and modify the class every time a new type is used.

Comment: You can wrap `A<T>` in a class that provides a free (friend) function to call `foo`, e.g. `template<class T> struct wrapper : A<T> { friend void bar(T t) { this->foo(t); } };` then `template<class... T> struct B : wrapper<T>... { template<class X> void foo(X x) { bar(x); } };`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183568/c-how-to-introduce-overload-set-from-variadic-number-of-bases

Comment: @dyp I'm tempted to write [the paper](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/ewg/issue102) myself, but someone is responsible... :/

Comment: @Columbo Why not contact Vandervoorde and ask if you can help.